# How can I test variance explained by the factor group if each subject in the group comprises a different number of measurements?

Tags: r, mixed-model, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

### The data structure

I have 2 groups with 30 subjects each. Each subject has a different number of fibers (approximately 46000 +/- 3000) of different length (see histogram). My goal is to determine how much of the observed variation in fibre length is explained by the factor group (A or B) correcting for the influence of subjects' age. I'd avoid aggregating the data over subjects, since I would reduce 46000 fiber lengths to a single value.

The data look like this:

```
line length     ID      age group
1     57.21179  a001    18  A
2     68.86046  a001    18  A
3    141.03307  a001    18  A
4     87.74376  a001    18  A
5     59.00859  a001    18  A
6    119.93846  a002    18  A
7     58.46695  a002    22  A
8    121.13653  a002    22  A
```

### This is what i have tried so far using R:

1. 2-sample t-test:

   `t.test(length~group, data=longdfr)`

   Result: t = -12.4432; df = 2772102; p-value < 2.2e-16
   The fact that the data was derived from different subjects is not considered in this apporach. Therefore I guess this is not a valid approach.
2. 2-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test:

   `ks.test(longdfr$length[longdfr$group=='A'],longdfr$length[longdfr$group=='B'])`

   Result: D = 0.0096, p-value < 2.2e-16
   The variances apparently are not equaly distributed. Like in the t-test i cannot correct for the subjects' age.
3. So I tried linear mixed-effects models using the `lme4` package:

   `lme.length <- lmer(length ~ group + age + (1|ID), data=longdfr)`

   ```
   REML criterion at convergence: 26425485
   Random effects:
   Groups    Name         Std.Dev.
   ID        (Intercept)  1.696
   Residual               28.289  
   Number of obs: 2774925, groups:  ID, 60
   Fixed Effects:
   (Intercept)     groupntc  
   81.4934         0.3779
   ```

With this approach I have two concerns. First, does lmer realy consider all fibres or does it use the same amount of fibres for all subjects. Second, does it consider subseqeunt fibres as repeated measures or as independent measures?

4. Since I like to get p-values I further tried `afex` package:

   afe.length <- mixed(length ~ group + age + (1|ID), data=longdfr)

With `mixed` again I have the same concerns as with the lmer model. Worse still, running the model results in the abortion of the R Session while obtaining 1 p-value.

### My questions:

**Is there a better statistic to test how much of the observed variation in fibre length (considering all fibers differing in number across subjects) is explained by the factor group?** -- I am afraid `lmer` or `mixed` might interpret different fibers as repeated measures.

**How can I deal with different fiber numbers across different subjects without aggregation +/- 46000 fiber measures to a single mean value?**

[image: length histogram]

Comment: This question: "Is there a way to consider all fibers and all subjects in a statistical model?" is unclear, could you be more specific? From your question is sounds like you are already doing so...

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I rephrased the questions and hope they are more precise now.

Comment: Is is still not clear... The only random effect you have in your model is `(1|ID)`. Also, please tell us what libraries you use, so there is no need to guess where does the functions you mention come from.

Comment: Good point. I used lm4 and afex package from the CRAN repository.

Comment: I think the problem you're having in getting answers may be that your focus currently isn't on the right question. Try making your question more about "how much of the variation is explained by," and put everything about mixed-models and your concerns in a subsection about "what I've tried." It's possible a reasonable answer might not involve a mixed model at all.

Comment: Thank you Aaron for your advice. It is the first time i post a question on stackexchange. Now I rephrased the question and listed the statisitics I have tried so far.